# Game character items LibGDX

Tags: libgdx, items

I'm working on simple 2D platformer game where player walk and collect items (like gun's, sword's, etc). So here is my player (or character)

```
public class CoolGuy extends GameObject {
    private Rectangle bottom, left, right, top, full;
    private Sprite sprite;

    public CoolGuy(){
        full = new Rectangle(0, 0, 50, 98);
        bottom = new Rectangle(0, 0, 50, 15);
        top = new Rectangle(0, 83, 50, 15);
        left = new Rectangle(0, 15, 25, 68);
        right = new Rectangle(25, 15, 25, 68);

        sprite = new Sprite(TextureManager.coolGuy);
        sprite.setSize(50, 98);
    }

    /* lots of code here */
}
```

also I have my Item class. When player collides with this class sprite (and rectangle) player should gain new power (like shooting and so on...)

```
        public class Gun extends ItemObject{

            private Sprite sprite;
            private Rectangle full;

            public Gun(int x, int y){
                sprite = new Sprite(TextureManager.gunItem);
                sprite.setSize(25, 15);

                full = new Rectangle(0, 0, 25, 15);

                setPosition(x, y);
            }

            @Override
            public int hits(Rectangle r) {
                if(full.overlaps(r)){
                    return 1;
                }
                return -1;
            }
/* lots of code here */
    }
```

And here is my new power class. In this case new power is shooting.

```
public class PlayerBullet extends ItemObject{

    private Sprite sprite;
    private Rectangle full;

    public PlayerBullet(){
        sprite = new Sprite(TextureManager.playerBullet);
        sprite.setSize(15, 15);
        full = new Rectangle(0,0,15,15);
    }

    @Override
    public int hits(Rectangle r) {
        if(full.overlaps(r)){
            return 9;
        }
        return -1;
    }
    /* A lot of code here */
}
```

So how I need to add this power to my player? I know I could have lots of booleans and even `PlayerBullet` object in my `CoolGuy` (player class) and set them all to **null** and later if player collides with my `Gun` class I could create new object and so on... But I believe there are other way.
[image]

Comment: There are infinite ways to do this, and you already mentioned one of the most straight-forward ways. Not sure what you are actually asking.

Comment: Ok, but if I have 20 items? Then I must have all items objects in my player class. I don't think this is good idea...

Comment: Put them in an List. Or use a boolean array where each index corresponds with an item type.

Answer (score 1):

Make a reference to an "ItemObject" in your player class and don't initialize it yet. This reference will keep track of your current powerup. When the player walks over the sprite, set the referance to that object. Now when you want to do item specific actions, put those actions/methods inside powerup class, which in your case is PlayerBullet. Now you don't need to check which item your player has and you can perform item specific actions efficiantly.
 CoolGuy class:

```
public class CoolGuy extends GameObject {
private Rectangle bottom, left, right, top, full;
private Sprite sprite;'

ItemObject currentItem;

public CoolGuy(){
    full = new Rectangle(0, 0, 50, 98);
    bottom = new Rectangle(0, 0, 50, 15);
    top = new Rectangle(0, 83, 50, 15);
    left = new Rectangle(0, 15, 25, 68);
    right = new Rectangle(25, 15, 25, 68);

    sprite = new Sprite(TextureManager.coolGuy);
    sprite.setSize(50, 98);
    }

public void equipItem(ItemObject item){
currentItem = item;
}

 /* lots of code here */
}
```

You can call this equipItem() method and pass it the object that collides with player. For using powerup, you can add another method to PlayerBullet or Gun:

```
public void ItemUsed(){
 //item use effect
}
```

And then make another method in Player and call ItemUsed from that method:

```
public void useItem(){
//check if player has any item 
if(currentItem != null){
//if it has then use item
currentItem.useItem();
}
}
```

Of course you will have to add an ArrayList or Array of you want to equip more than one item at a time.

This was just a sample or an idea for how you can implement what you want. You will have to do a few extra things to get it working.

Answer (score 1):

@user3334375 You Just Have to draw this box carefully. Mean that If you are giving some points with this Gun power box check that If points are counted then remove box. 
For example

```
if (!powerboxscored){Draw power box} //
```

this method takes powerboxscored boolean. 
If the boolean is false it will draw this box untill the boolean becomes true and it will only become true when u add power in ur code...

I hope it helps..